# Javascript neither then or await are waiting for the method to finish

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I feel like there is something essential that I don't understand, but googles results are all quite complicated. Please help me.

```
app.post('/api/trigger-push-msg/', function (req, res) {
  getAllSubscriptionsFromDatabase()
  .then(function(subscriptions) {
    console.log(subscriptions)
    ...
```

```
async function getAllSubscriptionsFromDatabase() {
  let subscriptions = [];

  await db.find({}, function (err,docs){
    subscriptions = docs;
    console.log("Docs"+docs)
    return(docs);
  })
  return subscriptions;
};
```

From my understanding it should wait for getAllSubscriptions. In that case it would print this:

Docs[object Object]

[object Object]

But it is printing this:

(0) []

Docs[object Object]

Comment: your await on the DB call probably isn't doing anything here

Comment: In order to wait for `getAllSubscriptionsFromDatabase` you might need to expose the returned promise to express. If you return it, it will might work. `return getAllSubscriptionsFromDatabase()...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankfully it looks like Express [supports promises in API callbacks](https://medium.com/@Abazhenov/using-async-await-in-express-with-node-8-b8af872c0016).

Something like this might work. By making the callback async we return a promise implicitly, ensuring Express knows to wait for the DB call.

The call to the DB needs to be converted to return a promise, in order that we can connect it to the promise chain.

```js
app.post('/api/trigger-push-msg/', async (req, res) => {
  const subscriptions = await getAllSubscriptionsFromDatabase()  
  console.log(subscriptions)
  // ...
})

function getAllSubscriptionsFromDatabase() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
    db.find({}, (err, docs) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(docs))) // is that first empty object correct?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what database software do you use, but the issue is likely that you've expected a callback-based API to behave like a Promise-based one.

If that's the case, you'll have to check whether your database software provides a Promise-based API, and if not, wrap the DB call into a Promise, like this:

```
const dbFind = (...args) => new Promise((rs, rj) => db.find(...args, (err, data) => {if(err) rj(err); rs(data)}))
```

So, this will probably work:

```js
const dbFind = (...args) => new Promise((rs, rj) => db.find(...args, (err, data) => {if(err) rj(err); rs(data)}))

async function getAllSubscriptionsFromDatabase() {
  const subscriptions = await dbFind({}) // <-- No callback! Result is "returned" by `await`
  
  console.log('Subscriptions (aka. docs)', subscriptions)
  return subscriptions;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `await db.find({}, callback)`.
The thing is most asynchronous functions don't return a `promise` if you pass in a callback function as the second argument.

Try to restructure your code like this, simple yet elegant -

```
async function getAllSubscriptionsFromDatabase() {
  let subscriptions = [];

  const docs = await db.find({});
  console.log(subscriptions);
  return subscriptions;
};
```